# Creating a hybrid SELinux policy for a specific directory?

Tags: rsync, redhat-enterprise-linux, nfs, selinux, tftp

I have a machine "NFS-Server", a machine "Hybrid", and a machine "TFTP-Client" which I would like to connect in the following way:

1. NFS-Server allows Hybrid to mount to a share
2. Hybrid also has a TFTP server at `/var/lib/tftpboot`
3. TFTP-Client gets files from Hybrid at `/var/lib/tftpboot`
4. Any files placed into the share on NFS-Server should be able to be pulled by TFTP-Client, so there needs to be some sort of living relationship between the NFS mount and the TFTP server directories.

What I have tried to far is:

1. Mounting `/var/lib/tftpboot` directly to the share. Whenever this happens, SELinux relabels the directory from `tftpdir_rw_t` to `nfs_t` so the TFTP permissions go away. I have not been able to mount with context options nor change the context after the mount.
2. Mount a different directory to the NFS share, and then bindmount that directory to `/var/lib/tftpboot`. Same results as above, even with the context options/commands.

What I have seen as potential next steps:

1. Create a simple service that does an rsync from the mounted NFS share and `/var/lib/tftpboot`. This would almost certainly work but I feel like there is a better way.
2. Create a custom SELinux rule/policy/module (the semantics are a bit confusing) that would give `/var/lib/tftpboot` a "hybrid" NFS/TFTP context that would allow it to mount and also serve files. This seems better but confusing.

Has anyone tried something similar, or could at least give guidance on what the better path forward is? Many thanks in advance!